# How to share JSON among multiple Highcharts on one page?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, arduino, setinterval

I am using Highcharts, with 4 gauges on the page, using setInterval to get JSON data feeding the charts.

I have it working by polling once per gauge.  But thats 4 times as much polling / bandwidth as needed.

Here's a stripped down version of the gauges.  http://jsfiddle.net/FredSmith/4Uqbc/

And here is what I'm using to poll once per chart in the currently wasteful setup:

```
    function(chart) {
        setInterval(
            function() {
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0], newVal;
                    $.get("get_JSON_from_Arduino.php", function(newVal) {   
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(newVal);
                        point.update(obj.humidity, true);
                    }
                );
            },1300
        );
    }
```

I imagine the challenge is related to global variables?  Not that great with JS..

Comment: What your php returns?

Comment: Sebastion, this comes from the php:    {"tempF":71.60, "tempC":22.00, "humidity":33.0, "tempF2":53.60, "tempC2":12.00, "humidity2":74.0, "motion_detected":0.0}

Comment: do you use json_encode() in php?

Comment: No, not using json_encode.

Comment: So you should use, to return json inside php. It should be echo json_encode($yourarray), then use $getJSON() and you will achieve your goal.

Comment: Done Sebastion.  Thank you for your help.  It was a combination of the changes you suggested, making the chart variables global, and fixing my javascript code.  Now I can have many gauges on one page with just one polling script. Cheers